# jsonwebtoken problem when deploying to AWS

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, debugging, jwt

So I have a problem, here it is :

1. I have a backend APP (let's say A/) which runs smoothly on local
2. When I pull to AWS, the APP gives :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jsonwebToken'
```

Here is the back story :
Before pulling the APP to AWS, I already have another APP (let's say B/) which also needs `jsonwebtoken`, and it runs smoothly.

Here is what I've tried :

1. After pull, I delete the `package-lock.json`, and do `npm i` again, still same error
2. I deleted the `jsonwebtoken` folder inside `node_modules`, still same error
3. I make a new instance in AWS, fresh re-install node, npm, mongo, still same error
4. I delete the `jsonwebtoken` folder on A/ `node_modules` and do `cp -r ~/from/node_modules/jsonwebtoken ~/to/node_modules/jsonwebtoken`, still same error
5. I didn't use the `jsonwebtoken` module, APP runs smoothly

Here is where I need help  with:

1. Are there any known bugs regarding `jsonwebtoken`?
2. Is the problem not `jsonwebtoken`?

Comment: am also getting the same issue, tried everything possible but still no success